# How to subset dataframe on lowercase values in multiple columns

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe like this:

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
  v2 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
  v3 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
  v4 = c(sample(LETTERS, 8), sample(letters, 2)),
  v5 = c(sample(letters, 1), sample(LETTERS, 7), sample(letters, 2))
    )
df
   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1   B  K  F  G  p
2   U  U  T  W  N
3   W  J  C  V  Y
4   G  I  Q  S  E
5   D  F  E  N  T
6   A  X  Z  T  C
7   V  Y  K  X  I
8   M  Z  D  Q  A
9   Y  L  H  k  d
10  R  B  L  j  t
```

I want to subset `df`on those rows that contain a lowercase value in any of `df`'s columns. It *can* be done like this:

```
df1 <- df[grepl("[a-z]", df$v1) | grepl("[a-z]", df$v2) | grepl("[a-z]", df$v3) |
          grepl("[a-z]", df$v4) | grepl("[a-z]", df$v5), ]
df1
   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1   B  K  F  G  p
9   Y  L  H  k  d
10  R  B  L  j  t
```

But this is uneconomical, if you have many (more) columns, and error-prone. Is there a cleaner, simpler and more economical way, preferably in base R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` per row and then use `grepl`.

```
df[grepl("[a-z]", apply(df, 1, paste, collapse="")),]
#   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1   B  L  L  M  e
#9   R  N  D  t  t
#10  F  X  M  h  x
```

Or another option is `do.call`

```
df[grepl("[a-z]", do.call(paste, df)),]
```

Comment: That's even cooler: not sure though I understand `paste, collapse=""`--what does it do?

Comment: `paste` gets a vector and with `collapse` it is joined. Try `paste(c("a", "b"))` and `paste(c("a", "b"), collapse="")`

Comment: So the paste here works *vertically*, by binding together the rows that satisfy the condition expressed in the `grepl`clause?

Comment: No it works *horizontal*, defined with the `1` in `apply`.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann `BLLMe`, `PJEPS`, ... `FXMhx`. Simply try `apply(df, 1, paste, collapse="")` to see the result.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for improving!

Answer (score 7):

```
df[rowSums(sapply(df, function(x) x %in% letters)) > 0,]
#OR
df[apply(df == sapply(df, tolower), 1, any),]
#   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1   B  L  L  M  e
#9   R  N  D  t  t
#10  F  X  M  h  x
```

Answer (score 6):

One option is to apply `grepl` on each column with `lapply` to create a `list` of logical `vector`s and `Reduce` it with `|`

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, grepl, pattern = "[a-z]")),]
#   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1   B  L  L  M  e
#9   R  N  D  t  t
#10  F  X  M  h  x
```

---

Or using `filter_all`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "[a-z]")))
#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  B  L  L  M  e
#2  R  N  D  t  t
#3  F  X  M  h  x
```

Comment: Pretty cool. The function `Reduce` is new to me: why is `|`enclosed in backticks?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann It is just to evaluate it correctly.  It could also work with single quotes